# How does monster health scaling work?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

Monster Hunter World has a bigger focus on multiplayer when compared to previous titles in the series.

Every quest can be completed in either singleplayer or multiplayer and to add to all of this you can use S.O.S signals to ask for help from other players during a quest (meaning players can join a quest in progress).

**My question here: How does the monster health scale? Here are some of my thoughts of how it might work**

- There is no scaling. Monsters have a fixed amount of HP that doesn't change depending on the players (essentially playing with 4 people makes the hunt quicker purely from a HP perspective)
- Monsters have scaling health. Going in with 4 players will cause the monsters to have more HP when compared to going in alone. (Same for 2 or 3 players).
- Something completely different.

**If there is some scaling in place how does it affect the S.O.S flare?**

- The health scaling is triggered as soon as the S.O.S flare is used regardless of whether a player joins or not.
- The health scaling starts it's effect the moment a player joins the quest.
- There is no health scaling for S.O.S flares
- Again something completely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as there are two hunters out on a quest at the same time, the quest is locked to multiplayer difficulty, even if the extra hunters leave after departing on the quest. Multiplayer difficulty also does not change based on the number of hunters. Hunting with 2 people or a full party of 4 will result in the same changes to the monsters.

This has been confirmed several times by the developers, but the most explicit mention of this was in [the latest Developer Diary](https://youtu.be/UhbGtCHxE34?t=8m23s).

While in multiplayer difficulty, the monster's values are multiplied in various ways, depending on the monster's tier, the quest's rank, and possibly other factors.
For a full list of singleplayer and multiplayer stats for every quest in the game, see [this document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l9DhgHH2JtPO-bn1-ir2UGOl5AjGrIny/view).
For a quick look at the multipliers for the hardest quests in the game, see [hexhexhex's data mining](https://twitter.com/mhhexhexhex/status/1089697629317955586).

Comment: As per update 10.11, this answer seems now outdated, and there now are three difficulties: single-player, duo, and full-party, and they scale accordingly whenever the party size changes.

Answer (score 6):

With [update 10.11](https://www.monsterhunter.com/update/mhw/uk/ver10_10.html) (the update for *Iceborne*, although the change does not require Iceborne), the dynamic difficulty settings had undergone a major revamp. See the section "Monster Adjustments" for more information.

- Now the difficulty is scaled according to the *current* number of players. This means that, when the number of hunters reduce from two to one, the difficulty will shift back to the singleplayer difficulty, shrinking the hit points and flinch points back to singleplayer ones as such.
- A new difficulty for two players is introduced. This has less hit points and flinch points than in the full-fledged multiplayer difficulty, but more than in the singleplayer one. From multiple expeciences, I suspect it to be the average of the singleplayer stats and the full multiplayer stats. Note that there is no exclusive difficulty for three players, and a party of three players will experience the same difficulty as in a full party.

Also, some High Rank-exclusive quests (namely Behemoth and Ancient Leshen) have their difficulty locked at the full party multiplayer difficulty.

Answer (score 5):

I can't remember where exactly it was said (I follow a lot of gaming news sites...) but in an interview with the Director, The Multiplayer works like this:

Single Player Monsters have less health (as it always has been)

Firing off an SOS does not increase monster health until someone joins, same with regular session joining. Once someone joins your quest, you will see a notification saying something along the lines of "increasing difficulty due to player joining"

The Monster Health difference between 2 players and 4 players isn't much, so full parties are far more optimal than duo teams.

Again... I'll try and find the interview where this was all said.

Comment: There is no difference between 2 or 4 player parties.

Comment: 2 player parties include your Palicoes. 4 players does not. I'm guessing 3 players only the host has his Palico, but I haven't checked it myself.

Comment: @CyberClaw 2 players + 2 palicoes. 3 players - 0 palicoes.

Comment: the 3rd player is way more value than 2 Palicoes

Comment: @Andrey that depends on the 3rd player...